# New Objects with Primary Key in Swift with Realm

Tags: swift, swift2, realm

**Background:**
I'm very very new to Swift but also programming in general, so apologies ahead of time. My only real database experience is MySql and even that isn't so hot.

I'm learning Swift + Realm by building a basic goals/habits tracking app.

**Task:**
I have a Goal object which includes a primary key called 'id'. A goal might be 'lose weight'. I also have a Streak object which includes 7 daily "check-ins". The user sets a goal, and checks-in each day.

Each goal can have multiple "streaks" e.g. after one 7 day sprint/streak, the user can start another. You can also have multiple goals. In order to achieve this, I was trying to replicate the functionality of an auto-incrementing ID for Goals, which is also a primary key. This would also be recorded in corresponding Streaks.

**My Problem:**
The problem I am having is that when I'm trying to store another goal, I get an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Primary key can't be changed after an object is inserted.'
```

This is the code in my AddGoalController. I've added comments to explain my thinking.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class AddGoalController: UIViewController {

   //set default ID for next goal object
    var newID = 1

//function to determine what the next ID needs to be.
    func getNextID() -> Int{

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let currentGoal = realm.objects(Goal)
//gets maximum ID in the Goal object
        let id = currentGoal.max("id") as Int?
        let goal = id != nil ? currentGoal.filter("id == %@", id!).first : nil
//figure if the query is empty, e.g. no goals at all. If it is not, increment the newID.

            if(goal != nil) {
                newID = goal!.id++
            }

        print(newID)
        return newID
        }

//if a button is pressed...
    @IBAction func goalButton(sender: UIButton) {


        // Generate the newID
        getNextID()

        let goalObj = Goal()
        goalObj.id = newID
        goalObj.Title = setGoal.text!
        goalObj.Aim = ""
        goalObj.Action = setHabit.text!
        goalObj.Active = 1

        // Get the default Realm
        let realm = try! Realm()
        // You only need to do this once (per thread)

        // Add to the Realm inside a transaction
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(goalObj, update: true)
}
```

In fact, even if I comment everything in the button and just have getNextID(), I still get the same error.

**My questions are:**
1. is there a more elegant way to achieve my aim of having a goal or goals with multiple streaks attached. Only the latest streak is active. 

2. what is causing this error?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newID` shouldn't be an instance variable, it should be returned from your function.

You also need to change `newID = goal!.id++` to `newID = (goal!.id + 1)` so that you aren't editing the value, you need to get it and add one to the result, not add one and then get the value.